# Interchange numbers in a column

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to interchange numbers inside a column of a table?
The numbers are always the same length, that is, 8. Here is an example:

```
^ before ^ after ^
|20150620|06202015|
```

It is a dateformat where I want to interchange the year at the end and the month at first.

Is it possible only on MySQL?

Comment: what's the type of this column?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Look into MySQL string functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html specifically `SUBSTR()` and `CONCAT()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a combination of CONCAT, RIGHT AND LEFT:

```
SELECT CONCAT(RIGHT(column, 4), LEFT(column,4)) as flipped from table
```

Of course, you can also use this in an UPDATE statement like:

```
UPDATE table set column = CONCAT(RIGHT(column, 4), LEFT(column,4))
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b5df)

Comment: Hi Michael, yeah Thank you very much for both queries, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Considering that the column is of `string/varchar` type you can use string functions like `LEFT/RIGHT` to get this done like

```
UPDATE your_table 
SET your_string_type_date_column = RIGHT(your_string_type_date_column, 4) + LEFT(your_string_type_date_column, 4)
```

Comment: @michael, I don't think so; only difference b/w our answer is that you are using `CONCAT` function whereas I am using concatanation operator.